# Can static properties return new instances of objects/classes in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, design-patterns

I am building an application in ASP.NET MVC 4. I am creating a class (similar to Factory type) that will return me instance of my service classes which i have made in BAL Layer. I want to declare static properties in that class and they should return Instance of requested Service Class.

My question is that is it possible that a static propery will return instance of new class because static property will be allocated a memory that will remain throughout the application. I am little confused here, Please explain what happens and what is best way to do so.

Code done so far

```
public class Factory
{
    public static CountryService CountryServiceInstance
    {
        get
        {
            return new CountryService(new CountryRepository());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Eh.. while you _can_ have getters return new instances each time and act like this it would be really confusing. Using getters for anything that's not accessing a logical (sometimes computed) property of the object they belong to tends to create confusing code.

Comment: then how it should be done ?

Comment: *because static property will be allocated a memory that will remain throughout the application* No, not really. If you're talking about static field yes. If you lost the reference somehow(by assigning null or another) and if you have no more references to it, it will be garbage collected. It is convoluted. Read more about garbage collection.

Comment: I'm with Benjamin here, properties returning new instances will make confusion. Instead create a method named `CreateNewCountryService`

Comment: @AnkushJain personally I'd pass it via dependency injection but if you want a factory then use a method rather than a getter.

Comment: @AnkushJain Definitely use a method.

Comment: well if i use DI, each class will have refrence of its dependent class. In that case what if have to call methods of another class whose refrence i do not have, then i will have to create that class's object

Answer (score 3):

What you should do  is write a function the will create the new instances not a get property

```
public class Factory
{
    public static CountryService CreateNewService()
    {
        return new CountryService(new CountryRepository());
    }
}
```

About your memory  concern read  Sriram Sakthivel's first comment
More about the Factory pattern here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817667.aspx

Answer (score 2):

A property in C# is just a method which returns what it should return in its body. In your case, each time you access that property, a new instance of the service will be created.

In case you want only one instance of that service, you might want to store it to the static private variable like this

```
private static readonly Lazy<CountryRepository> _fact 
    = new Lazy<CountryRepository>(() => new CountryRepository());
```

Also, a static properlty never stores something "in the memory throughout the application", but a programmer can do that.

Once again, a property is just a pair of set\get methods, unless you use an automatic property, where there is also a backing field created for the value to store.

A `static` keyword itself only specifies that a current class member must not be accessed though `this` keyword, and its value will be shared all across the appdomain (or your application).

Comment: can i have public static readonly variables rather than having them private. Secondly  if i have many service classes then such variables will be downgrading  performance of my application ?

Comment: @AnkushJain Hardly. If you leave only `static public readonly` variables visible from everywhere, then simple reading a variable by reference wont be a performance issue for your case.

Answer (score 1):

your method CountryServiceInstance for each call will always gives you a new instance of CountryRepository.

As you have mentioned, Most of the Factory classes are static which are responsible for creating new object instances. If they give the same object instance none of the factory patterns  will serve its intent.

you can undoubtedly proceed with your sinppet..

if you want to quickly validate you can check the created objects hashcode 
object.GetHashCode() they will be unique as they are separate objects